# 2D Nav Goal not working in Rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, remapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a Toyota HSR robot running ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic. I am having issues getting the move_base node to work by sending nav goals in Rviz. When I do `rostopic list | grep move` I see the following topic: /move_base/move/goal. However when I run Rviz, Rviz sends its 2D nav goals to the topic /move_base_simple/goal. I thought about just switching the topic that the 2D Nav goal publishes to but unfortunately the two topics do not have the same message types. /move_base/move/goal is of type move_base_msgs/MoveBaseActionGoal whilst /move_base_simple/goal is of type geometry_msgs/PostStamped. Currently I am thinking of writing a node that subscribes to /move_base_simple/goal and publishes to /move_base/move/goal but I am wondering if there is an easier way to go about this. Thanks for all the help!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import roslib
import actionlib

from std_msgs.msg import String, Empty
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from move_base_msgs.msg import MoveBaseActionGoal, MoveBaseGoal
from actionlib_msgs.msg import GoalID


'''def goal_client():
    client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('send_goal', GoalID)
    client.wait_for_server()'''
    


def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + ' I Heard %s', data.header.stamp)
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + ' I Heard %s', data)
    #rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + ' I Heard %s', data.pose.position)
    #rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + ' I heard %s', data.pose.orientation)
    #rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + ' I heard %s', data.header)
    pub = rospy.Publisher('move_base/move/goal', MoveBaseActionGoal, queue_size = 10)
    stuff_to_publish = MoveBaseActionGoal()
    stuff_to_publish.header = data.header
    stuff_to_publish.goal_id.stamp = data.header.stamp
    stuff_to_publish.goal_id.id = 'random_string'
    stuff_to_publish.goal.target_pose = data
    pub.publish(stuff_to_publish)        

def listener():

    # In ROS, nodes are uniquely named. If two nodes with the same
    # name are launched, the previous one is kicked off. The
    # anonymous=True flag means that rospy will choose a unique
    # name for our 'listener' node so that multiple listeners can
    # run simultaneously.
    rospy.init_node('navgoallistener', anonymous=True)

    rospy.Subscriber('move_base_simple/goal', PoseStamped, callback)

    #message = rospy.Subscriber('move_base_simple/goal', PoseStamped, callback)
    #print message.pose.orientation

    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()

"""def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('move_base/move/goal', MoveBaseActionGoal, queue_size = 10)
    rospy.init_node('navgoalsetter', anonymous = True)"""
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        listener()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300822/2d-nav-goal-not-working-in-rviz/) by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2018-08-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-08-18**:
I think you're on the right track, I can't think of an easier way to do this myself. Making such a node should be straightforward at least.

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-08-20**:
Thank you very much! I have begun writing the node although I am encountering issues because I do not know how to populate the header and goal_id sections of the move_base_msgs/MoveBaseActionGoal message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding your comment above the the documentation for the [goal_id part of the message](http://docs.ros.org/fuerte/api/actionlib_msgs/html/msg/GoalID.html) says the stamp is just the current time and the id can be any unique string (you could prefix a string to a string of the current time for this).

The header you can copy directly from the [geometry_msgs/PoseStamped message](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html) to the new move_base message.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE :**

Okay, you're almost there. The problem is that you're creating a new publisher object each time that a message is received, you should only create the publisher once as a global variable. The reason why no messages are being received is that a publisher object takes a small amount of time to register with any subscribers, so if you create it and instantly publish a message to it no nodes will receive it.

If you move the line `pub = rospy.Publisher('move_base/move/goal', MoveBaseActionGoal, queue_size = 10)` to the top of the code so it's global it should start working.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-08-20**:
I have edited my question to include the code where I try to do this. However it seems to be I am not doing it correctly as I get an error with this script. Can you suggest to me the correct way to publish the information I want to the new topic? Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-08-20**:
I've updated my code to get it work properly so that it publishes to the correct topic with the correct message type, however I still cannot get 2D Nav Goals from Rviz to work on my robot :(

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-08-20**:
This has worked! One final thing I had to change was the line `stuff_to_publish.goal_id.id = 'random_string'`  to `stuff_to_publish.goal_id.id = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(15)])` so that the goal_id was truly unique and now it works!

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-08-20**:
Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-08-20**:
Great. Glad you got it working!